# In mysql workbench, i am trying to create a simple function for my bike_store table. The query is given below, please suggest the solution

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bike_names
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
bike_name,
cost
FROM
store.bikes_store
ORDER BY bike_name
END;
```

while executing the above query, it will gives the syntax error at line 2 "AS keyword". please suggest the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

try this. mysql syntax is different from sql server. your stred procedure is similar to sql server.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE bike_names()
BEGIN
  SELECT bike_name, cost
  FROM
  bikes_store
  ORDER BY bike_name;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thankyou, Amit sir. Thankyou so much. I am trying to improve my skills in mysql workbench and Python libraries. for improving my skills in to get a Data_engineer job, i need to join a group releated to Data science and  Data Engineering in stack overflow team. How can join those kind of team's. Sir please guide me.

Comment: please accept the solution if this has resolved the problem.

Comment: But I invested my time.